# Determining in which quadrant an angle terminates.

Tags: trigonometry

Let $A$ be in the fourth quadrant and let $\sec(A) = \dfrac{13}{5}$, Let $B$ be in the third quadrant and let $\csc(B)=\dfrac{-5}{3}$. Find $\sin(A + B)$ and determine in which quadrant $A + B$ terminates.

$\sec(A) = \dfrac{13}{5} \Rightarrow \cos(A) = \dfrac{5}{13}$

$\csc(B) = \dfrac{-5}{3} \Rightarrow \sin(B) = \dfrac{-3}{5}$

$\sin(A) = \dfrac{-12}{13}$ and $\cos(B) = \dfrac{-4}{5}$

$\sin(A + B) = \sin(A) \cos(B) + \sin(B) \cos(A)$ 

after performing the substitutions, I arrive at $\sin(A + B) = \dfrac{33}{65}$

$\cos(A + B) = \cos(A)\cos(B) - \sin(A)\sin(B)$

= $\dfrac{5}{13}(\dfrac{-4}{5}) - \dfrac{-12}{13}(\dfrac{-3}{5}) = \dfrac{-56}{65}$

Comment: secant is the reciprocal of cosine. Cosecant is the reciprocal of sine

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that a few moments ago. However, even with that mistake I guess my question is still valid. How do you determine in what quadrant a sum of angle lies in if the two angles are unknown? So I have to specifically solve for A and B?

Comment: fixed the mistake

Comment: if you find both $\cos(A+B)$ and $\sin(A+B)$ you will know the quadrant. It would be enough  to know for sure what $\pm$ signs went with cosine, and which $\pm$ went with the sine. In your case, there is no difficulty finding the actual cosine and sine (for $A+B$)

Comment: I see. Yes, $\sin(A+B) = 33/65$ which is positive. Then the $\cos(A+B)$ is negative,  so second quadrant

Comment: FIND $\cos(A+B)$

Comment: So, there is no way to determine which quadrant $A + B$ terminates in without also computing the $cos(A + B)$ So it's really 2 questions in one?

Comment: according to my calculations. I have $cos(A + B)$ as positive

Comment: Please show the computation of $\cos(A+B) $ so I can see what you did with what numbers. Meanwhile, I will write it more carefully myself here at home

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities

Comment: I showed my computation for $cos(A + B)$

Comment: You have the rule for cos(A+B) incorrect. Please look it up and correct the above

Comment: I don't have the rule incorrect. I got it directly from the wiki page you linked to.

Comment: Should have a minus sign, $$ \cos(A+B) = \cos A \cos B - \sin A \sin B $$

Comment: my mistake, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your calculations above are correct (I cleaned them up a little bit).  If sine is positive but cosine is negative, what quadrant are you in?  Does this give a hint to $A + B$?